# How to access two models in a single view to print their fields using single html file?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have two models in my django application (Client and Installment). My models.py is given below:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.


class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    dob = models.SlugField(max_length = 100)
    CNIC = models.SlugField(max_length = 100)
    property_type = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    down_payment = models.IntegerField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('client_details',kwargs={ 'pk' : self.pk})

class Installment(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    installment_month = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    installment_amount = models.IntegerField()
    installment_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.installment_month

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('installment_confirmation')
```

And to show the client details I have a view called 'clientDetailView' and is shown below:

view.py

```
class ClientDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Client
    model = Installment
```

And the template for this is called 'client_details.html' is also given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "property_details/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<body>
  <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"><h3>{{ object.name }}</h3></legend>
  <article class="media content-section">
    <div>
      <p class="text-muted">Client CNIC: {{ object.CNIC }}</p>
      <p class="text-muted">Date of Birth: {{ object.dob }}</p>
      <p class="text-muted">Type of Property:  {{ object.property_type }}</p>
      <p class="text-muted">Date of Agreement: {{ object.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"><h5>Installment History</h5></legend>
  <article class="media content-section">
    <div>
      <!--<p class="text-muted">Installment Month: {{ object.installment_month }}</p>-->
      <table id="installmentTable" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th style="width:200px">Date</th>
          <th style="width:400px">Installment Month</th>
          <th style="width:100px">Amount</th>
        </tr>
        {% for installment in installments %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ installment.installment_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ installment.installment_month }}</td>
            <td>{{ installment.installment_amount }}</td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>

    </div>

  </article>
  <a class="btn btn-outline-info" type = "submit" href="{%  url 'add_installment' object.id %}" >Add New Installment</a>

</body>
{% endblock %}
```

Up to this point, When I click on the client name, it shows all the details of the client. But I also want to see the installment details of that particlar client in the form of table on the same 'client detail' page.

For that, I made a table and tried to access the fields of installment model.

But it doesn't show anything about installments.

I have a doubt that I am accessing the fields of client model using `object.name`, `object.dob` etc. And to print installments and I am also using `object.installment_month` etc.

How django can differenciate between two objects?

And I also tried to import both models in 'clientDetailView' as you can see above. but it gives the following error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/8/
Raised by:  property_details.views.ClientDetailView
No installment found matching the query
```